# Diplomacy rule application

Tags: diplomacy

The Diplomacy rules state that

> In some rare cases, orders are written so that an Army could arrive at its destination either by land or convoy. When this happens, the following qualifiers apply:
>
> If at least one of the convoying Fleets belongs to the player 
>      who controls the Army, then the convoy is used. The land 
>      route is disregarded.
>
> If none of the convoying Fleets belongs to the player who 
>      controls the Army, then the land route is used. However, the 
>      player controlling the Army can use the convoy route if he 
>      or she indicated “via convoy” on the Army move order 
>      in question.
>
> This prevents foreign powers from kidnapping an Army and convoying it against its will.

How would moving by convoy (regardless of whose Fleet is convoying) ever effect gameplay? How would it be any different from moving by land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.

A BEL-HOL
F NTH C BEL-HOL
F HOL-BEL

Two pieces can trade places if and only if one of them is convoyed. So in the above examples, BEL and HOL trade places because BEL is convoyed. Without the fleet to convoy, the two pieces in HOL and BEL would bounce and stay in their respective palces.

Comment: I would change this to if and only if at least one of them is convoyed. Because it is also possible with two convoy routes.